# Ionic debug TypeScript files with WebStorm

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, webstorm

I have an App implemented with Ionic v1.3.0. In WebStorm I tried running it in the browser, but I get an error in the Developer Console of Chrome:

> Uncaught module cordova/confighelper not found
>   cordova.js:891 deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
>   cordova.js:884 Channel not fired: onCordovaReady

So I tried running it with an Android Emulator via WebStorm and it works. I see the App, in WebStorm I have a Terminal-window which prints out infos.

But now to my question, I am kind of searching for a Bug. I hoped, that I could debug it in Chrome, because I kind of need to check the `$scope` variables.

There are some possibilities to maybe log it, but I also kind of need breakpoints and so on. How can I do this with my TypeScript files even though the Emulator uses the apk?

Answer (score 1):

Cordova debuging is not currently supported,please follow [WEB-14781](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14781) and linked tickets for updates